# Error rendering a table row in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my react code:

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var loading = <tr><td>one row</td></tr>;
        return(
            {loading}
        )
    }
});
```

I receive this error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: PostRow.render(): A valid React element
>   (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array
>   or some other invalid object.

But this works:

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <tr><td>joer</td></tr>
        )
    }
});
```

What's the problem with my code ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just return `loading`, omit `{}`

Comment: It works too! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All React variables should be enclosed within a HTML tag.

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var loading = <tr><td>one row</td></tr>;
        return(
          <div>
            {loading}
          </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the Pranesh answer, this code works:

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var loading = <td>joer</td>;
        return(
            <tr>
                {loading}
            </tr>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are assigning a variable a `JSX component` and just rendering that. It gives a violation because it may happen that you have assigned null to that variable and then you will just be returning null that is not possible. You need to return something. So just add your row in a component in the `return()` statement, it could be a `div` or a `table`

```js
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var loading = <tr><td>one row</td></tr>;
        return(
            <div>{loading}</div>
        )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<PostRow/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return { foo }` in ES6 is a shorthand for `return { foo: foo }` in older versions of JavaScript.

Which means that your render function returns a plain object, not a React component. This is how your code is transpiled by babel:

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    displayName: "PostRow",

    render: function render() {
        var loading = React.createElement(
            "tr",
            null,
            React.createElement(
                "td",
                null,
                "one row"
            )
        );
        return { loading: loading };
    }
});
```

You can just skip all these parentheses and simply return the variable:

```
var PostRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var loading = <tr><td>one row</td></tr>;
        return loading;
    }
});
```